# Python, Function refuses to update a MySQL value?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on an irrigation script for my Raspberry Pi3 and I've run into some trouble updating the database.

This is my current code (which is on a loop):

```
nirrigationtime = getseconds('temp_average','humidaverage','press_Average')
print("has received data from function about how much time to add, which is currently "),nirrigationtime

#Get the current database irrigation seconds value
current_seconds = dbfetch('NIGHT_SECONDS','weather_settings')
print("this is the current value in the database for irrigation "),current_seconds

#Update the current seconds value with the additonal seconds from the getseconds function
nirriupdated = nirrigationtime + current_seconds
print("new irrigation value will be "),nirriupdated

#Update database with new night time irrigation value
try:
    dbupdate('NIGHT_SECONDS','weather_settings','nirriupdated')
    print("database updated, sleeping for 1.5min")
except:
    print("update actaully failed?")

#Sleep for 1.5 minutes
time.sleep(90)
```

This produces this result in terminal:

```
has received data from function about how much time to add, which is currently  10
this is the current value in the database for irrigation  50.0
new irrigation value will be  60.0
database updated, sleeping for 1.5min
```

The problem however is that it never writes the updated value to database, and I'm tearing my hair over it since the update function works well in all other parts of the project.

This is the database update function:

```
#This function connects to database and updates the value in the selected column in the selected table to the set new value
def dbupdate(dbcolumn,dbtable,newvalue):
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","weather")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "UPDATE "+dbtable+" SET "+dbcolumn+" = "+newvalue
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql)
            db.commit()

        except:
            db.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
        return
    except:
        print("Database connection failed")
```

The database column is set to Decimal(5,2) and as mentioned, the function works well elsewhere..

Can anyone see something I can't?

Comment: You are trying to change the value to the **string** `'nirriupdated'`, which will fail. Remove the quotes.

Comment: Actually as you can see in the resulting prints in from terminal that actually worked well @ThierryLathuille. I solved it temporarily by moving the function into the same .py file as the rest of the code (I usually import them), and I added nirriupdated = str(nirriupdated) which allowed it to be added to the sql query which I realized failed since I tried to add an integer to the string for the sql variable. Strangely my code only works if I write the db update function in the same doc as the rest or the code. Importing the same function and running that don't work at all :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems I temporarily solved it.
By moving the dbupdate() function from my external functions.py file (which I always do and import them to the file I'm working on) to the current file the rest of the code is in, and adding nirriupdated = str(nirriupdated). I realized I was trying to append an integer (nirriupdated) to a string (sql variable), which didn't work.

The working code looks like this:

```
nirrigationtime = getseconds('temp_average','humidaverage','press_Average')

#Get the current database irrigation seconds value
current_seconds = dbfetch('NIGHT_SECONDS','weather_settings')

#Update the current seconds value with the additonal seconds from the getseconds function
nirriupdated = nirrigationtime + current_seconds
nirriupdated = str(nirriupdated)

#Update database with new night time irrigation value - For some reason, this doesn't work?
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","weather")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "UPDATE weather_settings SET NIGHT_SECONDS = "+nirriupdated
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()

except:
    db.rollback()
cursor.close()
db.close()


#Sleep for 15 minutes
time.sleep(900)
```

If anyone can help me understand why this doesn't work when run in the external functions.py instead of when the function is written in the file the rest of the code is in then I would be really grateful. Especially since I use the same function in the external file a bit farther up in this file without a problem. It's things like this that keep me up at night..